# Change default .RData name

Tags: r

How do I set a different default file name for the ".RData" file in R?  Something like "R.RData" would work.

I mirror to Box and it doesn't store filenames beginning with dots.

Comment: How are you creating this `.RData` file? Are you using `save.image()`? There's a `file=` parameter there you can use to make it whatever name you want.

Comment: Yes, I could do that each time.  I'm hoping to change the default.